# Doing division on a Decimal returns 0 when trying to return a percent

Tags: apex, math, percent

When I run the following code, it will return a 0. It should return 50.00.

```
System.Debug((100/200)*100);
```

I'm certain this is a simple solution. But haven't been able to find out the reason why. I have also tried it with decimals i.e.

```
System.Debug((100.00/200.00)*100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter should work. When you divide an `Integer` by an `Integer` you get an `Integer` back which has the same value as `Decimal.round(RoundingMode.DOWN)`.

```
system.assertEquals(0, 100/200);
```

However, when you divide decimals, you should get an exact value.

```
system.assertEquals(.5, 100.00/200.00);
```

Comment: I must of had a typo in my original code block. Thanks!